# How do I select a single row from duplicate resultsets?

Tags: mysql

I think I may be on the right track but something is missing from my select statement

[image]

I am trying select the unique items in the level column. Is there a better way write this?

This is the desired output:
[image]

Comment: Which rows don't you want?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please say your desired output.

Comment: My goal is to write 2 queries. One query that will list srid 191, 193, 195 and 197. The other query will list the other srid's. But the focus shouldn't be on srid but on the level. A little background: the level is duplicated because the first line is always the male golf rating and slope while the second is the female rating and slope.

Comment: Where - in the table - does it differentiate between male and female slope? Does it mean that all level will have two duplicates only (one for each gender)?

Comment: I guess i have been looking this data for so long that I know from experience that the male data is the lower of the two levels and the female data is the higher srid of the levels

Comment: If there's a specific column that can indicate which is which, that would be much easier but if there are none, at least you know one of the column can be used as indicator; for example, you said that you want to return 191, 193, 195 and 197 while the duplicates of those are 192, 194. 196 and 198 based on your data above. By the looks of it, there are two columns where the duplicates have none in common - `rate1` and `slope1`. If those two columns are significant in differentiating gender slopes, use it. Otherwise you may have to add another column just to store the gender.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, I'm just assuming that you wanted to show two sets of results; one is for male and the other is for female.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a work-around solution. By using a loop, I was able to supply the level and id:
I knew the Men slope/rating had the lower of the two srid. So I wrote the sql to limit the  results to the first one for the level, in this case white.
For the Female slope/rating, I just reversed the sql results and limit to 1 using ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1. To get all 4 levels (White, Red, Black, Blue) I used Php array_push in a for loop to get the desired slope and rating for both Men and Women for all levels.

[image]